# Can't test Cordova app when open it in browser

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I created a Cordova app using the 4.3.0 version and the project for an iOS project.

Whenever I open the ***index.html*** (www folder) file in a desktop browser, it gets stuck in an infinite loop requesting ***gap://ready***.

Why is this happening? How can I solve it?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT AND UPDATE:**

The iOS app was not working because there was a plugin missing: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md

I added it, then build the project again, and it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't test an iOS project on a regular browser, if you want to test on a browser, add browser platform

```
cordova platform add browser
```

then

```
cordova run browser
```

Comment: Thanks jcesarmobile. Still, when I run the XCode project, it doesn't work because of the same issue I described in the first place.

Comment: can you post your index.html?

Comment: I did what you said, and it actually works when doing `cordova run browser`. Now, when running the ios simulator, the app gets stuck. I'm using three events when to point to the remote url: 'deviceready', 'online' and 'offline'. The 'online' event is the one firing the redirection.

Comment: can you post your index.html?

Comment: put the document.addEventListener('offline', LHH.offline, false);
                document.addEventListener('online', LHH.online, false); inside the device_ready

Comment: I found the issue, it's on the question itself. Nevertheless, I'll accept your answer, since it gave light to the actual issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this way. Make your site in normal way using XAMPP/WAMP. Copy all the same code and folders. Then Check it. Whatever you make change in XAMPP Site, update it in PhoneGap. It is easier this way.

Comment: what? no, don't do this either. First of all, you don't need a XAMP/WAMP if you just have html,css and javascript, any browser can open it without a server. But anyway, you can't test cordova API this way, and copying every change from one place to another is madness

Comment: I just built the iOS app because the site is launched, and within the _index.html_ file, I'm just calling the remote url, but I keep getting this redirection as an infinite loop. One thing I did also, it to comment line 1047 from the cordova.js file, which basically tells the window to go there: execIframe.contentWindow.location = 'gap://ready';

Answer (score 1):

Both answers wrong. The most correct way is run in your phone simulator or actual device.

For android

```
cordova emulate android
```

For ios you need a Mac machine and Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The real issue was a missing plugin (see question).

Comment: this isn't even an answer, if the question is how to run on the browser? you can't answer, run it on android, lol