# ionic download file, save to temporary filesystem and open with default app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, fileapi

I've searched far and wide but couldn't find an appropriate answer for my use-case. Basically I'd like to download a base64-encoded file (could be a pdf, pgn, jpeg - using a pdf in the following example) from my backend, save it to  a `TEMPORARY` fileSystem folder, then open it - possibly using the appropriate app on the device, if present. Let `/file` be a route served by the following ASP.NET MVC WebAPI Controller:

```
public class FileController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/file/
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string fullPath)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        return result;
    }

}
```

I came up with the following AngularJS script:

```
$scope.download = function(fileName) {
    window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024*500, function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("TempDir", {create: true}, function(dirEntry) {
            dirEntry.getFile(fileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {
                $http.post("/file", JSON.stringify(fileName), {
                    headers: {Accept: "application/octet-stream"}
                }).success(function(res) {
                    fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileEntryContent) {
                        var blob = new Blob([res], {type: "application/pdf"});
                        fileEntryContent.write(blob);
                        //Now load file
                        $scope.load(fileName);
                    });
                }).error(function(err) {
                    console.warn(err);
                });
            }, function(err) {
                console.warn("getFile failed:", err);
            });
        }, function(err) {
            console.warn("getDirectory failed:", err);
        });
    }, function(err) {
        console.warn("requestFileSystem failed:", err);
    });
};

$scope.download("foo.pdf");

$scope.load = function(fileName) {
    window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024*500, function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("TempDir", {create: false}, function(dirEntry) {
            dirEntry.getFile(fileName, {create: false, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {
                //This is where the magic needs to happen!
            }, function(err) {
                console.warn("getFile failed:", err);
            });
        }, function(err) {
            console.warn("getDirectory failed:", err);
        });
    }, function(err) {
        console.warn("requestFileSystem failed:", err);
    });
};
```

I'm currently stomped at the loading phase: tried `window.open`ing the base64-encoded content of the file, `http.get`ting the `fileEntry.toURL()` but nothing seems to work. I checked out [Cordova's File Opener 2 plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileOpener2/) but it seems it can only open files stored on the device's sdcard or such. Any clue is welcomed! Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FileOpener2 plugin is pretty much you're only option I think - and it can work in this scenario. You'll need to make sure the file is saved outside your app's container on the device, as other apps cannot access this. You can find the file structure for each platform, and what is/isn't public, on the [plugin page](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file). You'll also need to save to different locations depending on the platform. This works for me:-

```
if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) storagePath = cordova.file.cacheDirectory + "/temp";
else if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) storagePath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "/yourapp/temp";
```

You can then use storagePath as the base for your targetPath when downloading. I would highly recommend using ngCordova. The sample below is partially based on something that I'm successfully using on iOS and Android but I haven't tested it

```
// add your options here, i.e. any headers you need to add to the request
var options = {};
$cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, true).then(function(result) {
    //On successful transfer try and extract the file object
    result.file(function (file) {
        var localFile = file.localURL;
        resolveLocalFileSystemURL(localFile, function (entry) {
            var nativePath = entry.toURL();
            // Open in another app, will fail if app doesn't exist that can open the mime type
            $cordovaFileOpener2.open(nativePath, mime).then(function () {
               // Success!
            }, function (err) {
               // Error!
            });
        }, function(error) {
            //handle error here
        });   
    }, function (error) {
        // handle error here 
    });        
}, function (err) {
    //handle error here
});
```

Comment: Hmm, does this mean I cannot leverage the FileSystem API and use the nested `window.requestFileSystem` => `fileSystem.root.getDirectory` => `dirEntry.getFile` calls as per my example? Because the `$scope.download` function works like a charm, it's the other bit that's giving me a headache! Thanks for your contribution anyhow!

Comment: There's possibly a way of doing it but you'd be better off rewriting it to use [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/) wrappers. I'll add an example as soon as I can. You'll also need to change your api so it responds to GET as opposed to POST requests (also POST should be for inserting data as opposed to requesting a resource).

Comment: Granted, I can change my api to use the GET verb instead. In the meantime I'll try to refactor my code to only use ngCordova wrappers as you suggest. Cheers.

Comment: P.S. The reason I tried to use the FileSystem API and avoid cordova plugins was to test it in a browser as much as possible.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example. If you want to run in a browser then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855486/cant-test-cordova-app-when-open-it-in-browser) answer might help you although I haven't tried this myself.