# Cordova iOS Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova

I created a cordova project, added the iOS platform and built the project. After that I opened the .xcodeproj in Xcode, built it and the homepage showed the sample app homescreen. I then created another js file with the following content in the Staging/js folder

```
function testLoad(){
    alert("Loaded!");
}
```

In index.html, I added

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myScript.js"></script>
```

and called the function

```
<body onload="testLoad()">
```

However no alert appears! How to fix? I am using xCode 7.2.1 and Cordova 5.4.1.

Comment: I'm not very sure what you are asking, I didn't find any file called app.js, I added a new .js file in the Staging/js folder

Comment: What is the location of your html and JS file? Is it Staging/www/?

Comment: html is in Staging/ and JS is in Staging/js/. I checked changing the paths it doesn't help.

Comment: Please post your full coding.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/94452798/testProj.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is due to the Content Security Policy set in index.html. As told on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10598, the tag should be set to

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Answer (score 0):

If your js is in Staging/js, then your script should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Staging/js/myScript.js"></script>
```

Anyway, you can debug with safari to look for errors, check this.

https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/

Comment: This doesn't help, by default the index.js was also added like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>`

Comment: Ok, look the debugger then and say what happens, if the function don't work or the script is not loaded

Comment: In safari it gives a series of pop-ups saying there is no application set to open gap://ready which is due to (http://stackoverflow.com/q/28855486/3169868)

Comment: If you add text into the html, is it displayed?

Comment: Yes, text on the HTML page is displayed.

Comment: There are some kind of bug with alerts in cordova IOS, I already wrote a question. Maybe this is your problem too (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358006/dialogs-not-showing-in-ios-cordova)

Answer (score -1):

I have run your project and found error. After solving error, I can able get alert.

Please chage your below code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Staging/js/myScipt.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myScript.js"></script>
```

And if still error/problem is there, let me know.

Comment: No, changing it to js/ does not help. I asked on their issue tracker page, but this doesn't help so far. [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10598?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel]