# dialogs not showing in IOS cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, uiviewcontroller, cordova-plugins

I have a cordova app, and I have to show several alerts.

In another app, in the same device, they work well, but I have a problem in my current app

when the dialog should show. It does nothing, but if I expand the notification bar, the dialog magically appears.

I am using cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.1.1 in both apps.

I found this JIRA

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9441

But I dont want to create a new plugin to fix this.

Are there any way to workarround this issue, or which plugin is on top of the UIVIewController?

Cordova version 5.3.3

cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.1.1

IOS version 9.1

Thanks

Comment: CB-9441 is fixed, but I don't think that's your problem. Anyway, use the latest version of the plugin (1.2.0) and try again. And provide your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused for a javascript error. I was in development process, and I had some crashes before this code. The javascript keeps working, but looks like that in ios, a new view instance is created after each crash, so fixing my javascript errors (totally unrelated with this), fixed this issue too