# NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL: execIframe.contentWindow.location = 'gap://ready'; Cordova js

Tags: cordova

I'm getting below error in console when I'm running cordova ionic app in browser. See below image :

[image]

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855486/cant-test-cordova-app-when-open-it-in-browser

Comment: I have checked that link but it is not helpful.